# What am I doing wrong for this SICP question in clojure?

Tags: clojure, sicp

I'm working through SICP in Clojure. I'm stuck on exercise 1.38.

In 1.37 I made recursive and iterative procedures to compute finite continued fractions, and then in 1.38 I'm supposed to use that code to estimate Euler's number where the fraction is:

N1/(D1+N2/(D2+N3/(D3...+Nk/Dk)))

Where e-2 is equal to this fraction where N is always 1 and D is 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 6, 1, 1, 8, ...

In order to compute e, I want to do:

```
(+ 2 (cont-frac-4 (constantly 1.0) d 10))
```

Where d is defined as:

```
(defn d [i] (if (zero? (rem (+ 2 i) 3)) (* 2 (/ (+ 2 i) 3)) 1))
```

This works with my recursive procedure:

```
(defn cont-frac-3 [n d k]
  (defn cont-frac-rec [i]
        (if (= i k)
        0
    (/ (n i) (+ (d i) (cont-frac-rec (inc i))))))
(cont-frac-rec 0))
```

But not with my iterative procedure: (I tried 2 ways and get the same incorrect result)

```
;; first iterative try
(defn cont-frac-4 [n d k]
  (letfn [(cont-frac-iter [i acc]
         (if (zero? i)
         acc
     (cont-frac-iter (dec i) (/ (n i) (+ (d i) acc)))))]
(cont-frac-iter k 0)))

;; second iterative try
(defn cont-frac-5 [n d k]
  (defn frac-iter [i result]
        (if (zero? i)
        result
    (frac-iter (dec i) (/ (n i) (+ (d i) result)))))
(frac-iter (dec k) (/ (n k) (d k))))
```

I used this as a reference, but it's not written in Clojure so I'm not sure what I'm missing: https://billthelizard.blogspot.com/2010/07/sicp-137-138-and-139-continued.html

Thank you for any advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first iterative procedure looks fine, what I think it's causing the issue is your definition of `d`, which needs to be rewritten to fit the iterative process. This worked for me, and gives the same result as the recursive procedure:

```
(defn cont-frac [n d k]
  (letfn [(cont-frac-iter [i acc]
            (if (zero? i)
              acc
              (cont-frac-iter (dec i) (/ (n i) (+ (d i) acc)))))]
    (cont-frac-iter k 0)))

(defn d [i]
  (if (= (mod i 3) 2)
    (* 2 (Math/ceil (/ i 3)))
    1))
```

The result is as expected:

```
(+ 2 (cont-frac (constantly 1.0) d 10))
=> 2.7182817182817183
```

Comment: Thanks Oscar!! That helps a lot. After seeing this, I went back and tried to make my iterative formulas work for the original d, and saw that I could change the (d i)'s to (d (dec i))'s. It never occurred to me to change d itself and now I know!

Comment: Thanks for letting me know how to do that, I'm new to stack exchange and had no idea. I just checked the green check!